# Card flip animation in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android

I am using FragmentStatepagerAdapter.My fragment is just atttached to a viewpager and is not inside a special container.the problem with setCustomAnimation is that if I want to use the flip-card effect, then I have to specify a container that contains the fragment which is to replaced with the animation.Possible solution??

Comment: i'm getting the same issue with FragmentStatepagerAdapter